# PHP Location header

Tags: session, redirect, header, location, refresh

I'm running into the apparently somewhat common "IE losing the session when the page redirects" problem.  In the Codeigniter docs it says with regards to using refresh vs location in header redirects "Location is faster, but on Windows servers it can sometimes be a problem." Does anyone know what specifically that is talking about? Turning to voodoo solutions here.... =\

Comment: `Location:` header (302 redirects in particular) always worked well for me (PHP running via FastCGI on IIS 6 and 7 under Windows Server 2003/2008 respectively). About 50-60 % of our customers using IE (different versions, v6 included) and we do not have such problems reported. But we are not using CodeIgniter -- just simple custom framework (better say, collection of handy functions).

Comment: I found the problem- I was doing a 302, write session/cookie data, then another 302 immediately.  Apparently that's problematic- half baked cookies or somesuch.  Shuffled the program flow around a little bit to cut out the extra redirect and it took care of the problem.  Code ended up being cleaner for it.  Live and learn.